# Bash: Reading a file, then separating good text and error text into new text files

Tags: bash

I have been stuck with this read function for the last few hours. I have looked all over Stack Overflow and online and can't work out how to use this read function. I am able to make it read the text file in a separate script but can't make it work in the script I am currently creating.

The script I am currently trying to create needs to read a text file called input.txt which contains MIPS Code. It needs to split the correct code in one file and the incorrect code in another file. E.g. "add $s0 $s1 $s2" would be correct and put in correct.txt while "add $s0 $s1 $z2" would be incorrect and put into incorrect.txt.

```
# Argument names.
file=$1
correct=$2
incorrect=$3

function usageMessage() {
echo "Please enter three arguments (the input file, correct instruction output file and incorrect instruction output file)."
echo "Usage: valspit [input.txt] [correct.txt] [incorrect.txt]"
}

function readTest() {
while read -r "$file"
do
echo "$file"
done < "$1"
}

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
usageMessage
exit 1
fi

if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
readTest
exit 1
fi
```

If anybody could tell me how to get my read function working, and also tell me how to make it read the file line by line then that would be great.

Thanks.

Edit, here is the input and expected output:
input.txt:

```
#input.txt     
add $s0 $s1 $s2    
sub $s2 $t0 $t3     
add $s0 $s1 $z2    
lw $t1 8($t2)    
addi $t3 $s0 -9    
sw $s3 4($t0)    
lw $t11 70000($s0)
```

incorrect.txt should output:

```
add $s0 $s1 $z2    
lw $t11 70000($s0)
```

while correct.txt should output the rest of input.txt

Comment: Please provide input and expected output

Comment: added the input and output

Comment: if you copy paste your script to http://www.shellcheck.net/ , you'll see that one of the complaints is that you are not passing any argument while calling `readTest` function but you are using `$1` in that function

Comment: before asking anyone to help, you need to learn indentation.  Also, if -ne, then if -q is really an else statement.  And why are you exiting the else as a failure?

Comment: @SaintHax the code is indented, just don't know how to use Stack Overflow to display that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the logic for validating MIPS codes, but here is what your code should look like so far.

```
# Argument names.
file=$1
correct=$2
incorrect=$3

function usageMessage() {
   echo "Please enter three arguments (the input file, correct instruction"
   echo "output file and incorrect instruction output file)."
   echo "Usage: valspit [input.txt] [correct.txt] [incorrect.txt]"
}

function validate() {
   string="$@"

   true         # not sure the logic that goes here
}

function readTest() {
   local file="$1"          # if we use $1 in a function, the function nees an argument

   while read -r line; do   # read into the variable line
      if validate "$line"; then
         echo "$line" >$correct
      else
         echo "$line" >$incorrect
      fi
   done <"$file"            # read from file passed to us
}

if [[ $# -ne 3 ]]; then
   usageMessage
   exit 1                   # exit 1 could have went in the function too
else                        # no need for two if's, an else works better
   readTest $file           # there was no reason to exit as a failure here
fi
```